# Insert array of objects in only one document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to insert a new document in my Mongo database like this:

```
MongoClient.connect(MongoURL, function(error, database) {
  var collection;
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  collection = database.collection(job);
  collection.insert(json, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    } else {
      return console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

And is working, but not like i want.

The 'json' is an array of objects, like this:

```
json = [
   {
       "name": "Paulo"
   },
   {
       "name": "José"
   }
   ....
]
```

So, my code is creating one document for object, and i want create just one document with the objects inside a property called json:

```
{
  json: [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
  ]
}
```

Is this possible?

I tried to use insertMany, also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one,

```
  var obj = {};
  obj.json = json;
  col.insert(obj, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    } else {
      return console.log(result);
    }
  });
```